# Format number - plus (+) sign

Tags: excel, vba, sendkeys

I set up macro, that fills my PDF form. I need plus sign in front of positive numbers, like +2,75. I'm using this bit of code.

```
Application.SendKeys Range("D" & CustRow).Value, True
```

I've tried to use this and many other variants. With no succes.

```
Application.SendKeys Format(Range("D" & CustRow).Value,""+"#.##;-#.##"), True
```

Can someone help me, please?

Comment: What do you mean by "PDF form", exactly? You say you're using Excel, but Excel isn't Acrobat...

Comment: Have you tried this as the format string instead? `"+#.##;-#.##"` - Not sure why you added those extra quotes.

Comment: @Dai The code opens up pdf documents, reads values from excel and then fills the pdf document.

Comment: @braX That was my first attempt, since it works in Excel. It doesn't work. I found the extra quotes somewhere, but they don't work.

Comment: Are you certain the PDF form fields allow the "+" symbol to be entered into them? Numeric inputs in most applications only accept "-" for negative numbers, but not "+" for positive numbers as it's redundant.

Comment: `""+"#.##;-#.##"` does not do what you think it does: the "+" in `""+` is a VBA string-concat operator; it is not a "+"-symbol in a string.

Comment: Anyway, "+" isn't a real key on your keyboard: what you want is  `Shift` + `=`.

Answer (score -1):

- There's at least 3 things wrong in your code:

  1. The symtax `""+"#.##;-#.##"` means *concatenate `""` (an empty-string) with the string `"#.##;-#.##"`* (i.e. the `+` is a VBA operator, not a SendKeys key).
  2. Assuming that you meant `"+#.##;-#.##"` instead, then that won't work either, because VBA's `SendKeys` treats the `+`, `^`, and `%` symbols as special symbols that represent the Shift, Ctrl, and Alt modifier keys respectively.
  3. Most importantly: there is no "+" key on a keyboard. To enter a "+" character you have to press `[Shift] + [=]`, therefore you need to send "`+=`" to Acrobat via `SendKeys`, with the numeric/digit characters to follow.
  4. While not "wrong" in this particular case, your code incorrectly assumes that a VBA `Format()` string will produce output that you can directly pass to `SendKeys` - but `Format()` and `SendKeys` both look-for and handle their own sets of special-characters and have their own escape sequences. You should `Format()` the Excel cell value first, then generate the `SendKeys` string from that string using intermediate variables: this will also help with debugging because right now you can't see what string is being sent to `SendKeys` (VBA's debugger is not very sophisticated seeming as it's essentially unchanged since *Office 2000*).

So try this: (I don't have an Acrobat form to test this with, so I don't know for certain if it will work or not)

```vb
Dim cellRef   As String : cellRef   = "D" & CustRow
Dim cellValue As Variant: cellValue = Range( cellRef ).Value
Dim formatted As String : formatted = Format( cellValue, "+#.##;-#.##" )
Dim keys      As String : keys      = Replace( formatted, "+", "+=" )

Application.SendKeys keys, True
```

Comment: Thanks so much. I read one of your answers before this and figured out I can set formatting in the form itself. Forms are allowing javascript code and this one worked: if (event.value>0){var cr ="+"}else{var cr=""}AFNumber_Format(2,0,0,0,cr,true).